# running a T4 on adding a class

Tags: c#-4.0, code-generation, t4

Using t4, I want when the developer **adds a class** which ends to Report keyword (e.g. CompanyReport), put some code in that class.

Imagine I create a class named CompanyReport, I want the class to be like :

```
public class CompanyReport : IReportItem
{
    private Company _company;

    public CompanyReport(Company company)
    {
        _company = company;
    }

    public ReportBookmark BookMark
    {
        get { return ReportBookmark.Company; }
    }

    public void Report(ISetBookmark wordReport)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using a customized *ItemTemplate for Visual Studio* or just a snippet. Both are quite easy to build and redistribute. I'am also not sure if it is possible to invoke some T4-Template on creating (and really ONLY on creating) a class.

Comment: A new template will do the job but not the snippets. I saw such a thing in MVC's controllers and it was quiet fascinating.